# How to print each letter vertically

Tags: java

I am trying to print each letter vertically as a table (like the picture attached). Right now this all are printing together as a string

```
Vertex       Distance from Source 

ABCDEFGH         0 

ABCDEFGH         4
```

---

```
void printSolution(int dist[]) {
    System.out.println("Vertex \t\t Distance from Source");
    char[] c = new char[]{'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'};
        for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
            System.out.println( new String(c) +" \t\t " 
               + dist[i] );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new String(c)` actually convert the char array to String. If you want only the character you should do

```
System.out.println( c[i] +" \t\t " 
               + dist[i] );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm getting this wrong. But it should be simple I guess. 
Here is a working code giving this output:

```
public class Main
{
    static void printSolution(int dist[]) {
    System.out.println("Vertex \t\t Distance from Source");
    char[] c = new char[]{'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'};
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
            System.out.println( c[i] +" \t\t " 
               + dist[i] );
               System.out.println('\n');
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        printSolution(new int[8]);
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. new String(c) was messing my output.